# Hibernate hql return object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

In the Hibernate HQL, I want to return an Object from HQL,

```
public class HqlReturnObject  implements  Serializable{ 
    String domain;
    String id;
    Object obj;

    public HqlReturnObject() {
        //super();
    }

    public HqlReturnObject(String domain, String id, Object obj) {      
        this.domain = domain;
        this.id = id;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    ......
}

String hql = "select new HqlReturnObject('order',salesOrderId,  document) from  ... ";  
this.getHibernateTemplate().find(hql);
```

the error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:88)
```

but I have defined a constructor in the `HqlReturnObject`.

Thanks

Comment: What does getHibernateTemplate().find() do? Which class/table do you select (mapping for properties salesOrderId and document)?

Comment: remove the constructor and try to print the result set. Some null values in the result set is creating the problem I believe.

Comment: I found out the reason, I need to use a.salesOrderId instead of salesOrderId. but the error message is very confusing.